# Wordpress Varnish vcl Configuration

Tags: wordpress, varnish, varnish-vcl

When I user apache in Varnish vcl config set :

```
.expected_response = 200;
```

and everything works correctly but when to install Litespeed I should change this parameter to :

```
.expected_response = 301;
```

What's the reason for this issue? Is this configuration right, or causing the other problem?

Answer (score 0):

Basically people using LiteSpeed Web Server may want to use LSCache instead of Varnish. There're many reasons but I am not going to explain here.

You said with Litespeed only expect 301 status. It's possible something in the rewrite rules causing it. Please share the status code with following command.

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" https://example.com
```

If it shows 301, then you may want to check your rewrite rules what making it different between Apache and LiteSpeed.

Best

Comment: `# curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" https://domain.tld`
301

What do you mean by that rewrite rule path? Where exactly should I check?

Comment: Good, 301 status code is what we are looking for. Please check if there's any .htaccess file on your document root folder? Can you share the content?

Comment: htaccess content:

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit`

Comment: It seems like a normal wordpress default rules. Litespeed and Apache shouldn't behave differently in such cases, If a URL shows 301 on Litespeed but 200 on Apache, It should be investigated by their support team and is not expected behavior. Unless you're using two different URL's, The response Code should be same on both web servers. You may contact hosting manager or support@litespeedtech.com